# Is it possible to get the values of the method parameters from the Context() in Play! 2?

Tags: playframework-2.1

Using Play!Framework 2.1.3, is there a way to get the value used in the URL from the matched routes?

An example to be more precise:

Routes:

```
GET /users/:name/:page      controllers.Users.list(name: String, page: Integer)
```

and this URL:

> /users/ben/1

Is it possible, from the `Context().current()`, to get the value `ben` and `1` without having to parse the `Context().current().path()` ?

Comment: I don't get... why you don't pass them as a `list(name: String, page: Int)` ?

Comment: Oh, it's just a forgotten copy/paste code, I fix it.

Comment: I need to have the parameters outside the Controller scope (I need them for the Session class I use)

Comment: Cyril, but you are passing the context as a param to your util class right? Show us a part of your approach

Comment: Like parsing the url via the `path()` ? Because it's what I do so far, but I wanted to know if the parameters given to the method were available somewhere in the `context()`

Comment: I didn't find it, unfortunately

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought, I'll parse the `path()` then. Thanks for your time :)